# Mobx action method after an axios delete call doesn't run at all

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, mobx

Everything works fine up until the TaskStore.fetchTasks() call. The data is deleted from the database, but if I console log anything past the axios delete call, it doesn't even show. This is causing my component to not rerender because the observable in the store is not being updated with the new data without the deleted value.

DeleteTask.tsx:

```
export default function DeleteTask(value?: any) {
  const deleteTask = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let data = { task: value.value.task };
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/test`, {
        data,
      });

      await TaskStore.fetchTasks();
    } catch (error: Error | any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

fetchTasks:

```
@action fetchTasks = async () => {
    try {
      const response: any = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/test');
      runInAction(() => {
        this.tasks = [];
        console.log('before pushing' + this.tasks);
        this.tasks.push(...response.data.recordset);
        console.log('after pushing' + this.tasks);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

in general you have to create type for what data comes from api.
then create an empty object array from from type then check the solved function do that and your problem will solved.

```
//Your Code  
   @action fetchTasks = async () => {  try {
       const response: any = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/test');
               runInAction(() => {
                 this.tasks = [];
                 console.log('before pushing' + this.tasks);
                 this.tasks.push(...response.data.recordset);
                 console.log('after pushing' + this.tasks);
              });
             } catch (error) {
               console.error(error);
             }
           };
```

Your Component

```
// Here you just call your delete function from task store and that's all

export default function DeleteTask(value?: any) {
  const deleteTask = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      TaskStore.deleteTask(data);
    } catch (error: Error | any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

the Code that is Solved
first you have to create a type for what data comes from api

```
  // create Type to get data from api and store in it
       interface Tasks {
                        // here any fields you get from api set here
                        id: number;
                        name: string;
                        // etc
                       }
```

Create empty array object from type

```
TasksList: Tasks[] = []; // for task List
```

your Fixed function

```
// added New Delete Function

@action deleteTask = async (data: any) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/test`, {
        data,
      });
      runInAction(() => {
       this.fetchTasks();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Fetch Function

```
@action  fetchTasks = async () => {
      try {
          // define your type for axios 
        const response = await axios.get<Tasks[]>('http://localhost:5000/test');
        this.TasksList = []; // Bring it out from Run in action
      runInAction(() => {
        // add Data with response in below line
        this.TasksList = response.data; //just sample assign response to Task List
         });
     } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
                     }
     };
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't include it in my original post but I did initialize an interface and have a tasks state.

interface Task {
  task: string;
}

public tasks: Task[] = [];

But the fetchTasks function still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @ChanKim Hi please check updated answer in fixed function part it may solve your problem

Comment: It does not work :( The first render is fine, and the data gets deleted from the database just fine, but the problem is it doesn't run the fetchTasks function right after the axios delete call. If I even try to console.log below the axios delete, it doesn't show.

Comment: then do this 
    **await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/test`, {
        data,
      }).then(()=>{ TaskStore.fetchTasks()});**
after delete success call fetchTask From store

Comment: It still doesn't rerender :( I even tried putting a console log: { data }).then(() => {
        console.log('a')
        TaskStore.fetchTasks(); and the console log doesn't even show.. I'm really confused

Comment: Updated the answer try to move your delete function to store after delete success call fetchTask in deleteTask funcition as i Updated the answer check and wish it will solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251197/discussion-between-mohammad-samim-safi-and-chan-kim).